# O que estou fazendo errado nesse exercício?

Tags: javascript

Escreva uma função que dado um total de anos de estudo retorna o quão experiente o usuário é:

```html
<script>
        function experiencia(anos) {
            switch (anos) {
                case anos >= 0 && anos < 1:
                    return 'Iniciante'
                case anos >= 1 && anos < 3:
                    return 'Intermediário'
                case anos >= 3 && anos < 6:
                    return 'Avançado'
                case anos >= 7:
                    return 'Jedi Master'
            }
        }
        var anosEstudo = 7;
        var final = experiencia(anosEstudo);
        console.log(final)
    </script>
```

O final dá undefined, o que está errado?

Comment: Você está usando o [`switch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) da maneira errada. Nesse caso, inclusive, me parece fazer mais sentido usar `if` e `else` mesmo

Answer (score 3):

o valor da operação no case `anos >= 0 && anos < 1` é um boolean.
seu switch está a comparar com `7 === true` ou `7 === false`.

Pra condições use o If

```html
<script>
        function experiencia(anos) {
            if (anos >= 0 && anos < 1) return 'Iniciante';
            else if (anos >= 1 && anos < 3) return 'Intermediário';
            else if (anos >= 3 && anos < 6) return 'Avançado';
            else return 'Jedi Master';
        }
        var anosEstudo = 7;
        var final = experiencia(anosEstudo);
        console.log(final)
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

A condicional `switch` avalia uma expressão, combinando o valor da expressão para uma cláusula `case`, e executa as instruções  associadas ao `case`.

Você pode usar `Blocos de código comuns` ou `Método para múltiplos casos`

```js
    function experiencia(anos) {
         switch (anos) {
             case 0:
                 return 'Iniciante'
             case 1:
             case 2:
                 return 'Intermediário'
             case 3:
             case 4:
             case 5:
                 return 'Avançado'
             case 6:
                 return 'To pensando'
             case 7:
                 return 'Jedi Master'
             default :
                 return 'Tem que estudar menos'
        }
    }
    var anosEstudo = 7;
    var final = experiencia(anosEstudo);
    console.log(final)
```

**Outra forma**

Basicamente, o JavaScript está tentando comparar a expressão entre parênteses com os valores dos casos.

`anos > = 6:` retornará verdadeiro (true), portanto cada `case` deve ser comparado com a expressão `true`

```js
function experiencia(anos) {
    switch (true) {
       case anos >= 0 && anos < 1:
           return 'Iniciante'
       case anos >= 1 && anos < 3:
           return 'Intermediário'
       case anos >= 3 && anos < 6:
           return 'Avançado'
       case anos >= 6:
           return 'Jedi Master'
       }
    }
var anosEstudo = 7;
var final = experiencia(anosEstudo);
console.log(final)
```